# Find file in Time Machine backup with command line

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine

I am looking for a specific file starting with "Screenshot 2019-07-11" with an unknown location in a Time Machine backup. I tried:

```
$ sudo find /Volumes/TimeMachine/ -type f -name 'Screenshot 2019-07-11*'
find: /Volumes/TimeMachine//.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
find: /Volumes/TimeMachine//Backups.backupdb: Operation not permitted
```

The error led me to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/162690/how-can-i-delete-time-machine-files-using-the-commandline), which uses `bypass` to execute a command, so I tried this command and got the same error:

```
$ sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass find /Volumes/TimeMachine/ -type f -name 'Screenshot 2019-07-11*'
find: /Volumes/TimeMachine//.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
find: /Volumes/TimeMachine//Backups.backupdb: Operation not permitted
```

How can I search for a file in a Time Machine backup with the command line?

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? -- When I want to use the `find` _command_ on my **Time Machine** backup, on **macOS High Sierra**, I literally use the following _command_ when targeting something that would be within my **Home** folder. e.g.: `find /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/*/Macintosh\ HD/Users/$USER -type f -iname 'Screen Shot 2019-10-07*'` I do not need to use `sudo`, or other _commands_, and it works as is, going directly to all the backups of my **Home** folder without the needless searching of everything outside of it. It's much faster this way too!

Comment: I'm on **macOS Mojave**. That command fails with `find: /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/*/Macintosh HD/Users/<username>: No such file or directory` (where `<username>` is my actual username). Even `cd`'ing into `Backups.backupdb`, I get: `ls: .: Operation not permitted`, without or with `sudo`. I believe that is why I needed `bypass`. Running it with your command afterwards, I still get `find: .: Operation not permitted`.

Comment: I guess something has changed with **Time Machine** backups between **macOS High Sierra** and **macOS Mojave**. Can't say for sure as I do not have a **Time Machine** backup on my **macOS Mojave** system, however, you might have to add **Terminal** to **Full Disk Access** in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** for it to work.  Also, you do not have a _backslash_ to escape the space in `Macintosh HD`, e.g.: `Macintosh\ HD`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a backslash to escape the space when running the command (`find /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/*/Macintosh\ HD/Users/$USER`), but the error message does not escape the space (`find: /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/*/Macintosh HD/Users/<username>`).

Comment: If my edit is accepted, it encompasses all these comments. How about we delete them all?

Comment: miguelmorin, I've rejected your edit but up voted your question so you get some additional reputation points.  I rejected it because it was not how I would have written it, but will add in the information from my comments to your OP into my answer and then delete them. I'll have to do it a bit later today though.

Comment: OK, that's fine, please comment here once you do it so I get a notification and delete these comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to access a **Time Machine** backup from **Terminal** on **macOS Mojave**, and later, you'll need to add **Terminal** to **Full Disk Access** in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** for it to work.

[image]

Comment: In macOS Big Sur, (11.6.3) if you try to access the Backups.backupdb folder you get a "rotten symlink" error.